# Salesforce Button Override for Lightning (Record New, Edit)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

[image]

Hello Guys,

in our org, we already overrided our Opportunity__c object New and Edit button with VF pages, currently we are implementing Lightning for Communities,

i created Lightning Component for Override and i selected that component to Override, Please see screen shot 
For Salseforce Classic - VF
For Lightning and Mobile - Lightning Component

but button is not showing in Lightning mode, (if i select No Override for all options then only i am able to see the New button)

any one help on this

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" access="global" >
```

Controller:

```
({
    createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Opportunity__c"
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this i found that we cannot Use Overrided buttons in Lightning, so we have to Create New buttons/components and we have to add using community builder

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=5